# Append returned data to different elements based on objects names

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do you append json returned objects to different elements based on the object's name? My JSON data is bigger than the following example so I wonder if it's a good idea to use if statement in `.ajax` for each object:

JSON Example Data

```
[{"name":"Europe","year":"2000"},{"name":"Asia","year":"2001"},{"name":"Africa","year":"2002"}]
```

HTML

```
<div class="Europe"></div>
<div class="Asia"></div>
<div class="Africa"></div>
```

JS

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "text.json",       
     success: function (data) {
     var item_html;

      $(data).each(function (index, item) {
        var name = item.name;
        item_html='<h3>'+name+'</h3><div>'+item.year+'</div>';
      });

      if (name == Africa){
        $('.Africa').append(item_html); 
      }
      if (name == Europe){
        $('.Europe').append(item_html); 
      }
      if (name == Asia){
        $('.Asia').append(item_html); 
      }

   },
   error: function () {$('.Europe').append("<b>No Results Returned</b>");}        
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your if block in `each`

```
$(data).each(function (index, item) {
    var name = item.name;
    item_html = '<h3>' + name + '</h3><div>' + item.year + '</div>';
    if(name == 'Africa') {
        $('.Africa').append(item_html);
    }
    if(name == 'Europe') {
        $('.Europe').append(item_html);
    }
    if(name == 'Asia') {
        $('.Asia').append(item_html);
    }
});
```

Comment: Missing `''` in the string literals

Answer (score 1):

I think since the name and class names are the same you can use it to find the target element within the `.each()` loop and set its content like

```
$.ajax({
    url: "text.json",
    success: function (data) {
        var item_html;

        $(data).each(function (index, item) {
            var name = item.name;
            $('.' + name).html('<h3>' + name + '</h3><div>' + item.year + '</div>')
        });
    },
    error: function () {
        $('.Europe').append("<b>No Results Returned</b>");
    }
});
```